# Getting an "undefined reference to" method issue (possible pointer issue)

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm very new to pointers so that's the only thing that I can think I'm missing here. The error I'm getting is "undefined reference to 'Supplier::sellStock(std::string const&, int)' " (the last part is my method that the compiler has a problem with.

```
#include "Supplier.h"
#include <iostream>
void RetailerOrder::fillOrder(Supplier &s) {
    int sold = 0; 
    for(size_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        if(manifest[i] != nullptr)
            sold = s.sellStock(manifest[i]->getSKU(), manifest[i]->getQuantity());
    }
    std::cout << "Amount sold: << sold << std::endl;
}

int Supplier::sellStock(const std::string &sku, int num) {
    int quantity = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        quantity = inventory[i]->getQuantity();
        if(quantity >= num) {
            inventory[i]->setQuantity(quantity);
            return quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

Also sellStock works on its own. Both of the arrays (inventory and manifest are a class type that I've also declared too, but they work too), and size_t arraySize is a static const declared in my .h file for each Supplier and RetailerOrder. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the `fillOrder` function as well? If using that one gives the same error, you're probably not linking the file.

Comment: I think it would be useful to see some details about what methods are defined in which files as well as how you're compiling all of them.

Comment: Are you getting a **compiler** error or a **linker** error?  It makes a big difference. If you are getting a **compiler** error, then my guess is that `sellStock()` is likely not actually declared in the `Supplier` class in `Supplier.h`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `sold = ...` be `sold += ...` instead? And maybe `inventory[i]->setQuantity(quantity); return quantity;` should be `inventory[i]->setQuantity(quantity-num); return num;`?

Comment: This is how it's getting compiled - g++ -std=c++11 -o TestRetailerOrder TestRetailerOrder.cpp Product.o RetailerOrder.o
RetailerOrder.o:                                                   This is the error I'm getting - In function `RetailerOrder::fillOrder(Supplier&)':
RetailerOrder.cpp:(.text+0x3b0): undefined reference to `Supplier::sellStock(std::string const&, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [TestRetailerOrder] Error 1

Comment: Mind posting Supplier.h? Sounds like `sellStock` is not defined (perhaps you typo'd its declaration as `SellStock` or something similar?) or you might've changed the parameters it takes and forgot to update its declaration.